# How does scanf work when called in the condition of an if or while?

Tags: c

I have seen this code and I'm wondering how does it work the `if (scanf)` and `while (scanf)`?

This program is checking the biggest number until no number is entered. I'm wondering how does it know when is a number entered and when is not because we have `if` and `while` after that. If we enter the number the while does go back at if or?

---

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int variable,max;

    if (scanf("%d", &variable)){
        while (scanf("%d", &max)){
            if (variable > max){
                max=variable;
            }
        }
        printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
    }
    else {
        printf("Is not an number\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `scanf` function family returns the number of items successfully scanned. Time to read the man page? If no integer is entered then `0` is returned.

Comment: This code doesn't compile at first place. `scanf("%d,&variable)` --> `scanf("%d", &variable)`

Comment: `if (scanf("%d",&variable)){` is weak code as it is true on  end-of-file.  Suggest `if (scanf("%d",&variable) == 1){`

Comment: This code is botched. `scanf("%d", &max)` is not what the author really wanted to be doing at that point. They are repeated scanning for a new `max`, comparing it to `variable`, possibly updating `max`, then throwing it away to read a new `max`. Likely they wanted to scan into `variable` and possibly update a `max` that they maintain, not discard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point.

Comment: I would use `max` in the first scanf and `variable` in the second. `max` should be the variable that remembers and stores the current maximum and should not be overwritten by user input. What happens to `max` when scanf fails and the while loop terminates? Is its value changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does `scanf` work when called in the condition of an if or while?

`scanf` returns the number of items matched, and this is a vital piece of information in order to use `scanf` correctly.

Many times we see code like this:

```
printf("enter the number of numbers: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("now enter the numbers:\n");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
```

Now, although code like this can work, it is very brittle and for that reason very poor.  The problem is that the return value from `scanf` is *not* checked.  If `scanf` fails (perhaps because the user enters a non-numeric character, or perhaps because the program encounters end-of-file), the program will misbehave, often rather badly.

When `scanf` fails, and returns a value indicating that it did *not* match the items expected, but the calling program ignores the return value, there are two huge problems:

1. When `scanf` fails to convert and return one of the values it was supposed to, it fills *nothing* into the variable. But if the calling program goes on to use it, this means it's typically using a garbage (perhaps even uninitialized) value.
2. When `scanf` fails to convert something (for example, when you tell it to match `%d`, but the user types letters instead), it leaves the unmatched characters on the input stream.  But if the calling program ignores the failure, typically it will go on and try to read another number, and another, but they'll all fail, and the program will never get past the bad input.

For this reason it's important to always (*always!*) check `scanf`'s return value, to make sure it matched as many items as you expected it to.  The above code could be improved like this:

```
printf("enter the number of numbers: ");
if(scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    printf("now enter the numbers:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) break;
    }
}
```

Now, if any call to `scanf` fails, the program won't go any further.

One more thing.  The posted code had lines like

```
if (scanf("%d", &variable)) ...
```

and

```
while (scanf("%d", &max)) ...
```

Although these follow the rule, and check `scanf`'s return value, they're *still* poor, because `scanf`'s return value is actually the number of items matched, or `EOF`.  But since `EOF` is a negative value (not 0), the posted code will wrongly continue if the input stream reaches end-of-file.

To make the point about `scanf`'s return value more clearly, consider the call

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

There are actually *four* possible return values:

2: Both `a` and `b` were properly filled in
1: `a` was filled in, but then something went wrong, and `b` was not filled in (perhaps the input was "1 x")
0: something went wrong right away, and neither `a` nor `b` was filled in (perhaps the input was "x y")
EOF: `scanf` reached end-of-file before it could read any characters for `a` or `b`

Comment: Is `while(scanf("%d",&var) == 1)` more foolproof than `while(scanf("%d",&var) != EOF)`?

Comment: Yes.  If you write `while(scanf("%d",&var) != EOF)`, it will go into an infinite loop if the input contains a non-digit character like `x`.